# Python builtins.ValueError

Tags: python, integer

I'm writing a program that opens a `numbers.txt` file in write mode and prompts the user to specify how many numbers are to be stored in it. Then the number is to be stored in the file. Which is where I'm getting the issue, a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:,` every time I get to 3 (1,2,3).

Here's the code:

```
f = open("numbers.txt", "w")
n = int(input("How many numbers? "))
print("Enter", n, "number")
for i in range(0, n):
    m = input()
    f.write("%s\n" %m)
f.close()
f = open("numbers.txt")
lines = f.readline()
f.close()
print("The numbers stored in the file are")

for line in lines:
   print(int(line))

print("The numbers in the file multiplied by 2")
for line in lines:
   print (int(line)*2)
```

Comment: How are you giving input?

Comment: @ozgur I didn't conveying my issue well enough so I show pictures.  http://m.imgur.com/9olqoZW,3KT8Z8Y thanks again

Comment: @Anand S Kumar, with integers.

Comment: You only read one line --> lines = f.readline()  It should be readlines() if you want to read the entire file.

Comment: @Curly Joe with the suggested changes,  the same problem persists.  Thanks

Comment: You have not provided the complete traceback so there is no way to tell where in the program the problem is.  I would guess that it is "print(int(line))" as line will still contain a newline and can't  be converted.  Try "print(int(line.strip()))".  If this is not the case then provide more info.  Guessing wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @CurlyJoe this was the initial problem, http://m.imgur.com/9olqoZW. After implementing suggestions I am no longer getting the exceptions, but the program isn't running as intended. http://m.imgur.com/aFD2qdv

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = f.readline()
```

This reads **one** line from the file, storing it as a single string.

```
for line in lines:
```

This therefore iterates over *that string*, *one character* at a time.

The first time through the loop, it gets the `'3'`, and the next time, it gets the `'\n'` (newline).

```
    print(int(line))
```

The newline, by itself, cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: That isn't what's happening though. After the initial input (5) it only let's me enter 3 integers before it executes the rest of the program.  http://m.imgur.com/aFD2qdv

Comment: What does print("Enter", n, "number") output.  If it is 3 then the program is doing what it is supposed to do.